# How to disable UITextview selection text, copy/paste UIMenuController but still have hyperlinks working [Not duplicate]

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, uitextview

I want to disable copy/paste menu and i'm using HTML tag in `UITextView` in which multiple hyperlinks and want to only disable menu.

My texview image

[image]

Comment: i use this code in subclass that can't press links in textview and not showing copy/paste menu.
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return NO;
}
then i write this code then allow to press links but in other text show "Define"
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
  if (action == @selector(selectAll:) && action == @selector(select:) && action == @selector(cut:) && action == @selector(copy:) && action == @selector(paste:))
   return NO;

 return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
plz help me in this case.

Comment: I exactly want as above question. U were found any solution for that ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

just try to create a subclass of UITextView that overrides the `canPerformAction:withSender:` method

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say it didn't work !!!!! Any other way ???

Answer (score 11):

You can play with this property:

[image]

and this one :

[image]

Comment: selectable property fix it. (I have UITextView subclass)

Comment: or in code `textView.selectable = false`

Comment: yeah but with that user cant select textview to write! question just asking to disable the actions!

Answer (score 8):

You need to create a subclass of UITextView and override the canPerformAction method.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(selectAll:) || action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: In order to do this, you need to subclass your UITextView and put this method.
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if (action == #selector(copy(_:))) {
            return false
        }
        
        if (action == #selector(cut(_:))) {
            return false
        }
        
        if (action == #selector(paste(_:))) {
            return false
        }
       
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }