# Disable Lookup in text selection - TouchScreenKeyboard IOS Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, input, text

I would like to remove the ability to select the text in a TouchScreenKeyboard text field (IOS), or disable the ability to lookup the text (see attached picture). I've seen some answer here on Stackoverflow talking about it but i'ts not for Unity.

Should i create a native plugin or is there an easier way to do this?

Some sources on similar issues:

[How to remove lookup & share from textview in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329280/how-to-remove-lookup-share-from-textview-in-swift-3)

[How to disable UITextview selection text, copy/paste UIMenuController but still have hyperlinks working [Not duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905725/how-to-disable-uitextview-selection-text-copy-paste-uimenucontroller-but-still)

[How to disable copy paste option from UITextField programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701019/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-from-uitextfield-programmatically)

Thanks!

[image]

**EDIT:**

A solution which is not optimal is to edit the Xcode project that is generated by Unity when building:

Open the Xcode project and add these two files NonLookupField.h and NonLookupField.m in Classes --> UI

**NonLookupField.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface NonLookupField : UITextField
@end
```

**NonLookupField.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NonLookupField.h"

@implementation NonLookupField

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:) ||
        action == @selector(selectAll:)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

@end
```

Replace all instances of UITextField with the newly created NonLookupField in keyboard.mm

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want this? This is usually a feature devs try hard to implement.

Comment: @LouisGarczynski Apple doesn't allow outgoing links in apps that are categorised in the kids section. The lookup functionality counts as outgoing link by apple reviewers.

Comment: Have you tried modifying the built xcode project to add the correct canPerformAction implementation ? It's a hack, but it might work temporarily.

Comment: Yeah, actually i managed to fix it overriding the UITextField with a custom @implementation. But it's not pretty!

Comment: Considering your post is the only one on the subject, would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @LouisGarczynski i edited the question with that solution.

Comment: Ideally you should answer it using the answer box, that way people can vote on it. That still works for me though, thanks for your addition.